# Why all VC++ project enables "EnableCOMDATFolding" option? Is it related with COM?

Tags: visual-c++, optimization, hyperlink, com

I create a normal console application project, without selecting the include files of ATL/MFC, then I open the .vcxproj file using notepad, still I found this:

```
<EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
```

I search MSDN and it says this link option is something related with optimization. Is it connected with COM technologies? Or COM here means common or something? What does it do?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not related to COM, but to handling of symbols in COMDAT sections. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834597/what-is-the-comdat-section-used-for

Comment: It is simply the default value for the linker's /OPT:ICF option for the Release configuration.  Project > Properties > Linker > Optimization.  Nothing to do with COM, no good reason to mess with it.