# weak symbols and custom sections in inline assembly

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, custom-sections

I'm stuck with a problem which is illustrated by the following g++ code:

frob.hpp:

```
template<typename T> T frob(T x);

template<> inline int frob<int>(int x) {
    asm("1: nop\n"
            ".pushsection \"extra\",\"a\"\n"
            ".quad 1b\n"
            ".popsection\n");
    return x+1;
}
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "frob.hpp"

extern int bar();

int foo() { return frob(17); }

int main() { return foo() + bar(); }
```

bar.cpp:

```
#include "frob.hpp"
int bar() { return frob(42); }
```

I'm doing these quirky custom section things as a way to mimick [the mechanism here in the linux kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/x86/exception-tables.txt) (but in a userland and C++ way).

My problem is that the instantiation of `frob<int>` is recognized as a weak symbol, which is fine, and one of the two is eventually elided by the linker, which is fine too. Except that the linker is not disturbed by the fact that the `extra` section has references to that symbol (via `.quad 1b`), and the linker want to resolve them locally. I get:

```
localhost /tmp $ g++ -O3 foo.cpp  bar.cpp 
localhost /tmp $ g++ -O0 foo.cpp  bar.cpp 
`.text._Z4frobIiET_S0_' referenced in section `extra' of /tmp/ccr5s7Zg.o: defined in discarded section `.text._Z4frobIiET_S0_[_Z4frobIiET_S0_]' of /tmp/ccr5s7Zg.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(`-O3` is fine because no symbol is emitted altogether).

I don't know how to work around this.

1. would there be a way to tell the linker to also pay attention to symbol resolution in the `extra` section too ?
2. perhaps one could trade the local labels for `.weak` global labels ? E.g. like in:

   ```
   asm(".weak exception_handler_%=\n"
       "exception_handler_%=: nop\n"
       ".pushsection \"extra\",\"a\"\n"
       ".quad exception_handler_%=\n"
       ".popsection\n"::);
   ```

   However I fear that if I go this way, distinct asm statements in distinct compilation units may get the same symbol via this mechanism (may they ?).

Is there a way around that I've overlooked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g++ (5,6, at least) compiles an inline function with external linkage - such as
`template<> inline int frob<int>(int x)` - at a weak global
symbol in a [[COMDAT]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1834597/1362568) [[function-section]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4274804/1362568) in
its own section-group. See:-

```
g++ -S -O0 bar.cpp
```

**bar.s**

```
    .file   "bar.cpp"
    .section    .text._Z4frobIiET_S0_,"axG",@progbits,_Z4frobIiET_S0_,comdat
    .weak   _Z4frobIiET_S0_
    .type   _Z4frobIiET_S0_, @function
_Z4frobIiET_S0_:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
#APP
# 8 "frob.hpp" 1
    1: nop
.pushsection "extra","a"
.quad 1b
.popsection

# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $1, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
...
...
```

The relevant directives are:

```
    .section    .text._Z4frobIiET_S0_,"axG",@progbits,_Z4frobIiET_S0_,comdat
    .weak   _Z4frobIiET_S0_
```

(The compiler-generated `#APP` and `#NO_APP` delimit your inline assembly).

Do as the compiler does by making `extra` likewise a COMDAT section in
a section-group:

**frob.hpp (fixed)**

```
template<typename T> T frob(T x);

template<> inline int frob<int>(int x) {
    asm("1: nop\n"
            ".pushsection \"extra\", \"axG\", @progbits,extra,comdat" "\n"
            ".quad 1b\n"
            ".popsection\n");
    return x+1;
}
```

and the linkage error will be cured:

```
$ g++ -O0 foo.cpp  bar.cpp 
$ ./a.out; echo $?
61
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed it's an effective way to discard the references to the discarded section. I couldn't find proper semantics for gas section groups beyond the terse binutils doc. It's not entirely clear to me when merging happens or does not happen, and whether I have full control of it.